# iMacros to extract google results

Tags: imacros

I'm trying to extract google search results using `iMacros`, it does extracts the `URL` but instead of saving it `redirected` to extracted URL.

```
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=NAME:q CONTENT=Jhony
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=NAME:btnG
'text input activated
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ONMOUSEDOWN:return* EXTRACT=HREF
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=links.csv
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}

SET !EXTRACT NULL
```

can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, this could help:

```
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=NAME:q CONTENT=Jhony
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:f ATTR=NAME:btnG
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:"r" EXTRACT=HTM
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/a href=\"(.*)\" onmousedown=/)[1];")
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=links.csv
```

Comment: well, this will only work if green link inside `_Rm` is complete, but what if the link is like this: `www.website.com..Cubic_Capacity`

Comment: Yes, it does extract the required stuff, but giving this error `Error -1250: JScript statement in EVAL contains the following error: Expected ';'. Line 19: SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/a href=\"(.*)\" onmousedown=/)[1];")`

Comment: ‘iMacros’ for Firefox works correctly with this statement, and for ‘iMacros Browser’ let’s make ‘EVAL’ as follows: `SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var s = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/a href=\"(.*)\" onmousedown=/)[1]; s;")`